# How to turn off Visual Studio 2010's new collapsible section mouse over highlighter?

Tags: visual-studio, editor

[image]

So it seems like the new VS highlights whole sections of code when the mouse is over the collapsible line on the far left of the IDE. I don't know what this feature is called but I couldn't see any option in the Options to turn this off.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: I started having an issue where the color used for highlighting was unreadable after installing DevExpress. The chosen answer fixed it though.

Comment: I don't know who adds these stuff to VS2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors.

Select "Collapsible Region" under the "Display Items" section.

Then set the "Item Background" to "Automatic" or the appropriate background color for your editor.